# Converting Coordinates To Block Position In Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, math, formula, array-formulas

So I have an isometric map (but it could just as well be a 2D map) and an int[] array to store all of the block IDs on that map.

The array looks something like this (for a 4 by 4 block map):

```
0 0 1 0 0 2 0 1 0 2 1 0 1 0 3 2
```

That would translate into this on the map (first square):

```
0 0 1 0    0 0 1 0
0 2 0 1    0 2 X 1
0 2 1 0    0 2 1 0
1 0 3 2    1 0 3 2
```

There is an X on the second square.

How could I calculate X's position in the array? I tried doing basic multiplication: `index = fieldWidth + fieldHeight` but I can't get it to work.

Also, how could I calculate X's coordinates using it's position in the array?

This is probably useful to anyone making 2D/isometric games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Position is zero-based (= starts with 0):

```
index = horizontalPos + verticalPos * 4
```

If it starts with 1 use:

```
index = horizontalPos - 1 + (verticalPos - 1) * 4
```

Get the zero-based Positions of X with index i in the linear array:

```
verticalPos = parseInt(i / 4); horizontalPos = i % 4;
```

**EDIT:**

To make it universally usable replace **4** with **number of columns** of your map.

Comment: Say the field is now 5 x 4, know which of these 4s would be verticalPos and horizontalPos?

Comment: All numbers used here are the `height`, means: `number of rows`you have. See my edit.

Comment: @Shark Sorry, english isn't my first language, I have mixed up `rows` and `columns`. Please see my EDIT now being correct.

Comment: @Martin_Ernst What's `i` by the way?

Comment: @Shark i is the index of an element in the linear array. The X in your example has i == 6. That way you can calculate its position in the isometric map. parseInt(6/4) == 1 --> `row 1`, 6 % 4 == 2 --> `column 2`.